# Busy/Wait Cursor in enthought traitsui

Tags: python, enthought

I am using the traitsui package from enthought.  I'm launching a gui like this:

```
appui = TestBenchUI()
appui.configure_traits()
```

Where `TestBenchUI` is a custom gui derived from `enthought.traits.api.HasTraits`.  Some of the gui operations take some time to complete, and I would like the gui to display a wait/busy cursor.  I've been unable to determine how to do this. Could someone please enlighten me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this import:

`from enthought.pyface.api import GUI`

Then when you need to show a busy cursor:

`GUI.set_busy()`